# Were there any Lost Tribe of the Sith members not on Kesh after Apocalypse?

Tags: star-wars

Aside from Vestara Khai, did any Sith escape or are all the rest on Kesh?

Comment: -1 for not linking to context (on Wookiepedia) for obscure EU canon events.

Answer (score 2):

Saba Sebatyne is off "hunting" Sith through most of the book. I would assume that if an author wanted to have a stray Sith or two on Coruscant I wouldn't think it would be frowned upon or against anything in the book. The Sith are masters of hiding after all.

Answer (score 1):

When the strike team led by Lady Rhea attacked the tribe of the sith vestara khai was the only one who survived.